# Using async function within useEffect - React.js

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, async-await

I am having issues rendering returned data using state variables in React.

After looking at similar issues, I now have my custom asynchronous function being called inside useEffect. The first time I load my page, the "mydata is" log entry shows a blank array, which is because the promise from my async function call hasn't been resolved yet. However, I can't figure out to stop getting the error TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'data[0][0]').

If I reload the page, then comment out the last two lines, save, then uncomment out the two lines, my page then renders correctly (because the data is cached?). But I can't figure out how to get it to wait to render the first time until the data variable has been filled. I have tried filling the div element with {data? data[0][0].stat.avg : ""} and get the same error.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import customAsyncFunction from "./Functions";

function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  const fetchInfo = () => {
    return customAsyncFunction().then((d) => {
      setData(d);
      console.log(d);
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchInfo();
  }, []);

  console.log("mydata is", data);
  return <div>{data? data[0][0].stat.avg : ""}</div>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> But I can't figure out how to get it to wait to render the first time until the data variable has been filled.

Because that's the wrong approach.  The component's rendering logic needs to be able to handle whatever the state is, whenever the state has that value.  Your state has two potential values, the initial default value and the updated value after the asynchronous operation.  And the rendering fails with that initial default value.

This will only check if `data` is [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy):

```
data ? data[0][0].stat.avg : ""
```

Which it is when it's an empty array:

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
```

However, an empty array doesn't have any elements, and you're trying to de-reference an element within it.

You can also check if it has elements:

```
(data && data.length > 0) ? data[0][0].stat.avg : ""
```

Or use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining):

```
data ? data?.[0]?.[0]?.stat?.avg : ""
```

Or initialize it to something that isn't truthy, such as `undefined`:

```
const [data, setData] = useState();
```

Comment: This worked, thank you so much. For some reason I thought empty arrays evaluated falsy.